# Build a hall plan in Flutter. What is the best solution?

Tags: flutter, svg, canvas, stack, interactive

I want to make an interactive  hall plan in Flutter, but I can't figure out how to implement it correctly.

[image]

**Key points:**

- the plan should scale without loss of quality.
- the view of the place should change slightly when you click

**The first option:** is to make it as a Canvas of a large size, and put it in the InteractiveViewer, but I do not know if it is possible to change the already drawn parts on tap?

**The second option:** is to make each place as an SVG with onTap event, and put it all in a Stack widget. And then again in InteractiveViewer. But there will be about 500 seats on the plan, and I'm not sure if the phone can handle scaling such a scene?

**Maybe there are other solutions?** I will be very grateful for the advice, I still have very little experience in Flutter.

Comment: why do you need `interactiveViewer`? do you want a pinch-zoom feature?

Comment: yes, I need pinch zoom ... but I thought InteractiveViewer is the only one method that I could realize it...

Comment: so use `InteractiveViewer` as a parent and `CustomMultiChildLayout` as a child

Comment: I haven't heard about it. Thanks, will read docs

Comment: Just read it. And why not to use Stack widget with absolute positioning of children widgets? 
like 

`<div id="parent" style ="position: relative">
    <div id="seat1" style="postion: absolute; top: Xpx; left: Ypx "><img>/div>
    <div id="seatN" style="postion: absolute; top: Xpx; left: Ypx "><img>/div>
</div>`

in CSS

Comment: because you dont know the size of the stack - you have to know it if you want to evenly distribute your hall seats to available space - with `CustomMultiChildLayout` you not only know the size, but also you can position your children at will and finally you can have dynamic relayout used for some nice animations

Comment: But I know it. I receive XML file  from backend and know all sizes in advance: of screen, of places, rows and so on.  That's how it works in web: click on any time of session https://kinoteatr.ru/film/gucci/ (sorry, it's russian ;) )

Comment: but you dont know the size of the screen where all the seats have to be rendered to - it can be presented on variety of different devices

Comment: And why it is a problem? ... for example: the device is 700px width, I will render the image with hall plan 800px width, and place it aligned with center of the device screen. The user can drag it, scale it with his preferences using "InteractiveViewer". Am I wrong?

Comment: the problem is that you cannot initially present the hall in "full screen mode" - the user has to do that - this is bad UX

Comment: -- First idea: I will build it in real size, and then - quickly scale it down to fit the screen  with Animation controller. 

-- Second Idea: build it with opacity(0), then rescale, then set opacity(1). 

It's web way that works on JS very quickly... maybe it's bad for Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with InteractiveViewer & GridView:

for any shape of place, you can draw it using 2d array, like

```
  List<List<int>> triangleHall = [
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  ]

  List<List<int>> arcHall = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  ]

  List<Widget> _generateHallItem(List<List<int>> hall){
    List<Widget> list = [];

    hall.map((row) {
      row.map((item) {
        item == 0 ? list.add(Container(width:5, height:5)) : list.add(Container(width:5, height:5, color: Colors.red));      
      });      
    });
    return list;
  }

  Wrap(
    children: _generateHallItem,
```

OR

```
  InteractiveViewer(
    minScale: 0.8,
    maxScale: 2.0,
    child: GridView(),
  ),
```

Comment: But places in hall can be in random position, not a grid view. They can be placed by the  arc path opposite the screen

Comment: what about use 2d array to shape your hall?

Comment: Hall can be any shape, like this: https://explosion.ru/pic/12.jpg, maybe I didn't describe the task properly

Answer (score 0):

try `InteractiveViewer` and `CustomMultiChildLayout` as a child (notice how easy you can animate the seats inside `CinemaDelegate` with passed `AnimationController`):

```
class CinemaHall extends StatefulWidget {
  const CinemaHall({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CinemaHallState createState() => _CinemaHallState();
}

class _CinemaHallState extends State<CinemaHall> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late List<Offset> positions;
  late List<ValueNotifier<bool>> states;
  late AnimationController ctrl;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    positions = [
      ...List.generate(8, (index) => (Offset(index + 1, 0))),
      for (int r = 1; r < 7; r++)
        ...List.generate(10, (index) => (Offset(index.toDouble(), r.toDouble()))),
    ];
    states = List.generate(positions.length, (index) => ValueNotifier(false));
    ctrl = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () => ctrl.forward());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ColoredBox(
      color: const Color(0xff000044),
      child: InteractiveViewer(
        minScale: 1.0,
        maxScale: 3.0,
        child: CustomMultiChildLayout(
          delegate: CinemaHallDelegate(ctrl, positions, const Size(64, 64)),
          children: List.generate(positions.length, (index) => LayoutId(
            id: index,
            child: FittedBox(
              child: ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
                valueListenable: states[index],
                builder: (context, state, child) {
                  return TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    tween: Tween(end: state? 0.8 : 0.2),
                    builder: (context, t, child) {
                      return IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(index == 43? Icons.people : Icons.person, color: Colors.white.withOpacity(t)),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        iconSize: 64,
                        tooltip: 'seat ${positions[index].dy.toInt() + 1}, ${positions[index].dx.toInt() + 1}',
                        onPressed: () {
                          states[index].value = !state;
                          print(index);
                        },
                      );
                    }
                  );
                }
              ),
            )
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    ctrl.dispose();
  }
}

class CinemaHallDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  final AnimationController ctrl;
  final List<Offset> positions;
  final Size seatSize;
  late Size cinemaHallSize;

  CinemaHallDelegate(this.ctrl, this.positions, this.seatSize) : super(relayout: ctrl) {
    double cols = positions.map((o) => o.dx).reduce(max) + 1;
    double rows = positions.map((o) => o.dy).reduce(max) + 1;
    cinemaHallSize = Size(cols * seatSize.width, rows * seatSize.height);
  }

  @override
  void performLayout(ui.Size size) {
    final matrix = sizeToRect(cinemaHallSize, Offset.zero & size);
    final seatRect = MatrixUtils.transformRect(matrix, Offset.zero & seatSize);
    final center = size.center(Offset(-seatRect.width / 2, -seatRect.height / 2));

    int childId = 0;
    final constraints = BoxConstraints.tight(Size(seatRect.width, seatRect.height));
    final t = Curves.bounceOut.transform(ctrl.value);
    for (final position in positions) {
      layoutChild(childId, constraints);
      final offset = Offset(
        seatRect.left + position.dx * seatRect.width,
        seatRect.top + position.dy * seatRect.height);
      positionChild(childId, Offset.lerp(center, offset, t)!);
      childId++;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(covariant MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) => false;
}

Matrix4 sizeToRect(Size src, Rect dst, {BoxFit fit = BoxFit.contain, Alignment alignment = Alignment.center}) {
  FittedSizes fs = applyBoxFit(fit, src, dst.size);
  double scaleX = fs.destination.width / fs.source.width;
  double scaleY = fs.destination.height / fs.source.height;
  Size fittedSrc = Size(src.width * scaleX, src.height * scaleY);
  Rect out = alignment.inscribe(fittedSrc, dst);

  return Matrix4.identity()
    ..translate(out.left, out.top)
    ..scale(scaleX, scaleY);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but  It's really hard for me ;) ... it's my first app, and I can't even undestand what is going on. In the web it's really easy: make an SVG, place all the seats as independent objects and add event listeners on each, with css animations.

Comment: I guess my knowledge at Fultter is not enough ) ... Just slighly understand the logic.   Don't understand animation at all, and class CinemaHallDelegate  at all.  I understand the perpose of this class, but could find out how seats positioned, how animation works, what is sizeToRect and performLayout. I'll return to this, in two month, I have it to learn Flutter better. Thank you!

Comment: `performLayout` is called when the framework needs to size / positions the children of `CustomMultiChildLayout` and to position each seat `final List<Offset> positions` list is used - did you try to run it? if so add some `print` inside `performLayout` and watch the logs

Comment: Should I place this code inside MaterialApp widget?

Comment: yes as any other widgets: MaterialApp > Scaffold > CinemaHall, more: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/codelab#step-1-create-the-starter-flutter-app

Answer (score 0):

I tried various manual methods but none worked for me, Then I found [This](https://pub.dev/packages/book_my_seat) package.
Its Example app has static seats but we can make it dynamic by using List.generate() & State Management[image]